# $|x-y|<\delta \implies |x^2-y^2|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Problem Statement:

Given $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, show that for some $\delta>0$, if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|x^2-y^2|<\epsilon$.

---

Attempt (Incomplete):

$|x^2-y^2| = |x+y||x-y| < (|x|+|y|)(|x-y|) < \underbrace{(|x-y|+2|y|)(|x-y|)}_{(1)} < \hspace{2mm} ?$

I've been told that I can take $\delta = \min(\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}, \frac{\epsilon}{4|y|})$ with the idea being described below as continued from $(1)$:

$$(|x-y|+2|y|)(|x-y|) < |x-y|^2+2|y||x-y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon $$

I'm not entirely convinced as it seems like $\delta$ takes $2$ minimums here?

Comment: It looks like $\epsilon$ is also a given, despite not being declared as such, and $\delta$ should be qualified by "there exists...".  Otherwise, yes, it appears you have listed out the proof and filled in for your $?$.  Can you be more specific with your question?  What do you mean by "two minimums"?

Comment: Hi @abiessu, I've corrected it. What I meant by two minimums is here: $$|x-y|^2+2|y||x-y| < \delta + 2|y|\delta = \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}\bigg)^2+2|y|\bigg(\frac{\epsilon}{4|y|}\bigg)$$ Here $\delta$ takes two values. I think this is only possible if $\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} == \frac{\epsilon}{4|y|}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is almost entirely correct. There is a small problem: $y$ may well be $0$. So, I would define$$\delta=\begin{cases}\min\left\{\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon2},\frac\varepsilon{4\lvert y\rvert}\right\}&\text{ if }y\neq0\\\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon2}&\text{ if }y=0.\end{cases}$$Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: Hi @Jose Carlos Santos, my confusion is more with the fact that in the same expression we're using $\delta$ to represent two things. Specifically, $$|x-y|^2+2|y||x-y| < \delta + 2|y|\delta = \bigg(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\bigg)^2+2|y|\bigg(\frac{\epsilon}{4|y|}\bigg)$$ Here we can see $\delta$ takes two different values in the same expression? Like the only way that I can see for this to be valid is if it just so happens that $\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}} == \frac{\epsilon}{4|y|}$...

Comment: You seem to think that $\delta$ is equal to both numbers $\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon2}$ and $\frac\varepsilon{4\lvert y\rvert}$. Not at all! The number $\delta$ is defined as the *smallest* among these two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $|x -y | < \delta$ it follows that $y-\delta  < x < y + \delta$. Hence we get

$$|x^2 - y^2| = |x+y||x-y| \leq |x+y|\delta < |2y+\delta|\delta,$$

so if you put $\epsilon = |2y+\delta|\delta$ then you don't need to use the minimum.